# Java DbUnit information schema MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, dbunit

I use Java with a MySQL database and when I try to run a test I got message :

> org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'my_table' in information_schema

It's look like DbUnit can't access to metadata of the table.
Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the Java/SQL code which caused this error.  It looks like maybe you aren't connecting to the right database.

Comment: I use a file load.xml to load it in a DataSet.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
 <MY_TABLE Col1= "1" Col2="11000" Col3="ABC" />
</dataset>`

I load the content to a InputStream and get my DataSet like below (xmlDsBuilder is a FlatXmlDataSetBuilder) :
`IDataSet dataSet = xmlDsBuilder.build(inputStreamXml);`

If I write a bad table name I got :
`org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: MY_TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 3):

I have encounter same problem. It seems that current version of `DBUnit` (2.6.0) is not compatibility with latest version of `mysql-connector-java`. I fixed it by change the version of `mysql-connector-java` to `5.*.*`.

If it doesn't work. You could try to specify the schema yourself. To do it, you need to create a `IDataBaseConnection` bean

```
@Bean("mysqlTestSource")
public IDatabaseConnection databaseConnection(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException, DatabaseUnitException {
    return new MySqlConnection(dataSource.getConnection(), YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME);
}
```

And then ask DBUnit to use this connection by adding this annotation to your test class

```
@DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection = "mysqlTestSource")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a schema confusion problem - the [AmbiguousTableNameException](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AmbiguousTableNameException) FAQ entry should resolve it.